# What is the proper way to check that the background color is not something in Cypress

Tags: cypress, chai

Currently I am trying to create a test like the following...

```js
cy.get(".communications-icon")
    .should("have.css", "background-color")
    .not("eq", "rgb(232, 238, 242)");
```

But when I run the test I get...

> cy.not() failed because it requires a DOM element.
>
> The subject received was:
>
> ```
>  > rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
> ```

How do I check to make sure an element doesn't have a particular BG color?

Comment: Can you share the html ?

Answer (score 3):

Add the value as a third parameter, and prefix `not` inside the assertion

```js
cy.get(".communications-icon")
  .should("not.have.css", "background-color", "rgb(232, 238, 242)")
```

or equivalent

```js
cy.get(".communications-icon")
  .should("have.css", "background-color")
  .and("not.eq", "rgb(232, 238, 242)")
```

---

`.not()` command ***is valid syntax*** but it's the opposite of `.filter()` command and it requires one or more elements passed from the previous line.

The `.should("have.css", "background-color")` changes the subject from an element to the color string `"rgb(232, 238, 242)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `.not()` directly like `cy.not()`.
We can use it on DOM elements like `Cy.get('id').not('.class')` basically it is used for filtering elements.

For your case have u tried using this

```
cy.get('.communications-icon').should('have.css', 'background-color').and('eq', 'rgb(232, 238, 242)')
```